# Are questions about tool making on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm interested in making some tools such as knives including a draw knife, axe handles, as well as some shop machinery.

Are questions about particular aspects of the making process of the above on topic here? Or am I better to ask them on [**DIY**](http://diy.stackexchange.com) or [**Woodworking**](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crafting tools is... a craft. :)

Considering we have many questions about selecting tools, I don't see why questions about making them would be unwelcome.